# Degree of a projective variety consisting of finitely many points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Joe Harris's "Algebraic geometry, a first course", and on page 6 example 1.2 he says any finite subset $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a variety. Also if $\Gamma$ consists of $d$ points, it may be described by polynomials of degree $d$ or less.

Why is that true? Lets say the point is given in homogeneous coordinates by $[1,2,3]$ in $\mathbb{R}P^n$, how is it the zero locus of a homogeneous polynomial of degree 1?

Comment: Polynomial**s**, not just one polynomial. I'm sure you can find some homogeneous polynomials of degree 1 that cut out that point.

Comment: Polynomial**s**, not necessarily just one. That point can be written as the intersection of any two of the infinitely many lines passing through the point.

Comment: Oh, I see, for example we take two polynomials $2x-y$ and $3x-z$.